# Open Mappings Between $L^1(\mu)$ an $C(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $C(\mathbb{R})$ be equipped with the compact-open topology.  What are some examples of open mappings $F:L^1(\mu)\rightarrow C(\mathbb{R})$ or $G:C(\mathbb{R})\to C(\mathbb{R})$ which are *not* homeomorphisms?

So far, I've only found examples when the involved maps are homeomorphisms..

Comment: Oh, in general if $U$ is an open subset of $Y$, then is $C(X,U)$ and open subset of $C(X,Y)$?....actually this makes sense... I didn't realize...  

Nice... but what about $L^1$...this would probably be more challenging?

Comment: Oh wait... we're of course only dealing with the locally uniform topology. My bad. $C(\mathbb{R},(0,1))$ is not open, then (for $f$ mapping into $(0,1)$ and $K>0$, you can find $g$ within $\varepsilon$ distance of $f$ on $[-K,K]$ such that $g(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$).